# Generate lists by grouping all IDs in a dictionary using python

Tags: python, json, list, dictionary

I have this json and I want to extract only follower_ids w.r.t project_id into a list as :

```
followers_ids_for_01 = [123,124,...]
followers_ids_for_02 = [125,126,...]
```

**Json List :**

```
{
    "data": [{
        "id": 01,
        "followers": [{
            "id": 123,
            "name": "Shivkumar"
        }, {
            "id": 124,
            "name": "Sneha"
        },
        {
            .....
        }],
    }, {
        "id": 02,
        "followers": [{
            "id": 125,
            "name": "Teja"
        }, {
            "id": 126,
            "name": "Harsha"
        },
        {
            ......
        }],
    }]
}
```

What I tried :

```
data  =json_list
projects = data['data']

followers_ids =[]
for project in projects:
    for i in project['followers']:
       followers_ids.append( i['id'])

print followers_ids
```

Output:

```
[123, 124, 125, 126]
```

Can someone suggest How to **generate list** for "`followers_ids_for_{project_id}`" and add its respective followers ids in it?

**Edit/Update:**

I need to generate named variables for blank lists

```
datalists = dict()
for project in projects:
    datalists["followers_ids_for_{}".format(project['id'])] = []

print datalists
#{'followers_ids_for_1': [], 'followers_ids_for_2': []}
```

Comment: You will need a dictionary, you cannot "generate lists" otherwise.

Comment: yes..I already went through some other answers like https://stackoverflow.com/a/42768290/6107715 still I m looking for a solution where I can get named blank lists

Comment: You mean, you want to have many separate variables names `followers_ids_for_01`, `followers_ids_for_02`, and so on?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Yes.. If I go for dict , it will be like this : {'followers_ids_for_1': [], 'followers_ids_for_2': []} but I can use them as lists to add followers_Id

Comment: @BHappyBHarsham Why do you need `''followers_ids_for_...'` within your dict? Why not store the id in dict and create the string when you need to display the content. Your requirement doesn't makes any sense

Comment: @MoinuddinQuadri I was trying to know the usage and limitations of list here. thanks for your suggestion

Comment: @BHappyBHarsham Also, variables are used for the code. I don't think you'll ever need the problem where you'll have to dynamically generate the variable name, though you can do it by [hacks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45606063/2063361) but it is not something you'll encounter in real life

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing you do is to build a dictionary in the format you want:

```
In [514]: f = {'followers_ids_for_%s' %d['id'] : [x['id'] for x in d['followers']] for d in data['data'] }; f
Out[514]: {'followers_ids_for_01': [123, 124], 'followers_ids_for_02': [125, 126]}
```

I recommend you *stop here*. However, here's the second, and ***highly non-recommended*** step (which comes from your [hard requirement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45605649/any-better-way-to-generate-lists-and-group-all-id-into-a-list-using-python?noredirect=1#comment78170646_45605649)): Update `globals()`.

```
In [516]: globals().update(f)

In [517]: followers_ids_for_01
Out[517]: [123, 124]
```

Now you can access those variables as lists. Once again, this is bad, as it pollutes your globals.

Comment: Actually I was trying to know the usage and limitations of list here for this scenario. You have given for such a better Explanation. thanks a lot

Comment: @BHappyBHarsham I'm glad you accepted the other answer, but I thought this was what you wanted.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a list comprehension instead

```
[follower['id'] for project in projects for follower in project['followers']]
```

if you were only interested in a particular project id

```
[follower['id'] for project in projects for follower in project['followers'] if project['id] == 'some id']
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use nest *dict comprehension* expressions to create the `dict` object`:

```
>>> {val['id']: [item['id'] for item in val['followers']] for val in data['data']}
{1: [123, 124], 2: [125, 126]}
```

Let's say the above dict is stored in variable `result`. Then you may access the element in dict corresponding to each *so called project id* as:

```
>>> result[1]    # For id '1'
[123, 124]

>>> result[2]    # For id '2'
[125, 126]
```

PS: `data` variable in the above dict comprehension holds the value of your JSON object, i.e. :

```
{
    "data": [{
        "id": 1,
        "followers": [{
            "id": 123,
            "name": "Shivkumar"
        }, {
            "id": 124,
            "name": "Sneha"
        }],
    }, {
        "id": 2,
        "followers": [{
            "id": 125,
            "name": "Teja"
        }, {
            "id": 126,
            "name": "Harsha"
        }]
    }]
}
```

Comment: Thanks for such a better Explanation